# My existing filters list is not being updated In the UI

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am working on a component in my .net Blazor App and as the title states I am having an issue where the existing filters I am iterating through dont get updated in the UI when the method ("filterExistingFilters") that is tied to the oninput directive fires off. As of right now the only way I am able to fire off this method is when I click on the temporary button I have created the calls the function with an onclick event but my desired outcome is for the existing filters list to update whenever the user types in something into the input

```
@inject IJSRuntime jsRuntime



<h3>New Filter</h3>

<div style="display: flex; margin-bottom: 5vh ; border-bottom: 1px solid grey;padding-bottom: 10px;">
    <div style="margin-right: 1vw">
        <select @bind="selectedDepartment1" class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
            @foreach (var dept in myList)
            {
                <option value="@dept.Id">@dept.Name</option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-right: 1vw;margin-top: 1vh;">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right"></i>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-right: 1vw">
        <select @bind="selectedDepartment2" class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
            @foreach (var dept in myList)

            {

                <option value="@dept.Id">@dept.Name</option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>

    <div style="margin-right: 1vw; margin-top: 1vh;">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right"></i>
    </div>

    <div style="margin-right: 1vw">
        <input @bind="notes" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Notes" aria-label="default input example">

    </div>
    <div>
        <button @onclick="AddFilter" type="button" class="btn btn-success">New Filter</button>

    </div>
</div>


<div>
    <h3>Existing Filters</h3>
    <div>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search Filters" aria-label="default input example" @bind="searchStringFilters" @oninput="filterExistingFilters">
        <button @onclick="filterExistingFilters" class="btn btn-success">filter existing filters</button>
        <p >@searchStringFilters</p>
    </div>
    @foreach (var filter in filters)
    {
      
        <div>
            <span>Departments: @filter.Department1.Name, @filter.Department2.Name - Notes: @filter.Notes</span>
        </div>
    }
</div>


@code {

    public class DeptClass
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Filter
    {
        public DeptClass Department1 { get; set; }
        public DeptClass Department2 { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }
    }


    List<DeptClass> myList = new List<DeptClass>();
    string[] departmentNames = { "Mathematics", "Science", "English", "History", "Art", "Music", "Physical Education", "Computer Science", "Foreign Languages", "Special Education" };
   public  List<Filter> filters = new List<Filter>();

    int selectedDepartment1;
    int selectedDepartment2;
    string notes;
    string searchStringFilters { get; set; }


    protected override async void OnInitialized()
    {
        // Generate 10 departments
        for (int i = 0; i < departmentNames.Length; i++)
        {
            myList.Add(new DeptClass { Id = i, Name = departmentNames[i] });
        }
    }



    void AddFilter()
    {
        var filter = new Filter
            {
                Department1 = myList.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Id == selectedDepartment1),
                Department2 = myList.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Id == selectedDepartment2),
                Notes = notes
            };

        filters.Add(filter);
        Console.WriteLine($"Search term: {searchStringFilters}");

        // Clear inputs after adding filter
        selectedDepartment1 = 0;
        selectedDepartment2 = 0;
        notes = "";
        
    }

 void filterExistingFilters()

    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Search term");
    
        filters = searchStringFilters != null
         ? filters.Where(f => f.Department1 != null && f.Department1.Name.Contains(searchStringFilters)).ToList()
         : filters;
    }



}
```

apologies in advance if the code isnt the best , I just started learning how to program with c# language. If someone could point out what I am doing wrong and why this function is only working with an onclick event it would be greatly appreciated

I have tried adding an oninput directed thats tied to a method where the filtering logic takes place, but it doesnt seem to be working

Answer (score 0):

Your input needs to implement the binding correctly to update `searchStringFilters` on each input.  `filterExistingFilters` is now called after the bind set.

```cs
        <input class="form-control" type="text"
               placeholder="Search Filters"
               aria-label="default input example"
               @bind="searchStringFilters"
               @bind:event="oninput"
               @bind:after="filterExistingFilters" />
```

Add an `IEnumerable` to filter `filters`.  Read up about `IEnumerables` if your not sure how they differ from Lists.

```cs
    private IEnumerable<Filter> _filteredFilters = Enumerable.Empty<Filter>();
```

Update the displayed list

```cs
    @foreach (var filter in _filteredFilters)
    {
        <div>
            <span>Departments: @filter.Department1.Name, @filter.Department2.Name - Notes: @filter.Notes</span>
        </div>
    }
```

Update the filter method.

```cs
    void filterExistingFilters()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Search term: {searchStringFilters}");

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchStringFilters))
        {
            _filteredFilters = filters;
            return;
        }
        _filteredFilters = filters
            .Where(f => f.Department1 != null && f.Department1.Name.Contains(searchStringFilters));
    }
```

Finally sort out `OnInitialized`.  Remove the `aync` [this is not an async method] and set the initial filter to `filteredfilters`.

```cs
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        // Generate 10 departments
        for (int i = 0; i < departmentNames.Length; i++)
        {
            myList.Add(new DeptClass { Id = i, Name = departmentNames[i] });
        }
        _filteredFilters = filters;
    }
```

My updated version of your component looks like this in case I missed anything:

```cs
@page "/"
@inject IJSRuntime jsRuntime

<h3>New Filter</h3>

<div style="display: flex; margin-bottom: 5vh ; border-bottom: 1px solid grey;padding-bottom: 10px;">
    <div style="margin-right: 1vw">
        <select @bind="selectedDepartment1" class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
            @foreach (var dept in myList)
            {
                <option value="@dept.Id">@dept.Name</option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-right: 1vw;margin-top: 1vh;">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right"></i>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-right: 1vw">
        <select @bind="selectedDepartment2" class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
            @foreach (var dept in myList)

            {

                <option value="@dept.Id">@dept.Name</option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>

    <div style="margin-right: 1vw; margin-top: 1vh;">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right"></i>
    </div>

    <div style="margin-right: 1vw">
        <input @bind="notes" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Notes" aria-label="default input example">

    </div>
    <div>
        <button @onclick="AddFilter" type="button" class="btn btn-success">New Filter</button>

    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <h3>Existing Filters</h3>
    <div>
        <input class="form-control" type="text"
               placeholder="Search Filters"
               aria-label="default input example"
               @bind="searchStringFilters"
               @bind:event="oninput"
               @bind:after="filterExistingFilters" />
        <button @onclick="filterExistingFilters" class="btn btn-success">filter existing filters</button>
        <p>@searchStringFilters</p>
    </div>

    @foreach (var filter in _filteredFilters)
    {

        <div>
            <span>Departments: @filter.Department1.Name, @filter.Department2.Name - Notes: @filter.Notes</span>
        </div>
    }
</div>

@code {

    public class DeptClass
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Filter
    {
        public DeptClass Department1 { get; set; }
        public DeptClass Department2 { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }
    }


    List<DeptClass> myList = new List<DeptClass>();
    string[] departmentNames = { "Mathematics", "Science", "English", "History", "Art", "Music", "Physical Education", "Computer Science", "Foreign Languages", "Special Education" };
    public List<Filter> filters = new List<Filter>();

    private IEnumerable<Filter> _filteredFilters = Enumerable.Empty<Filter>();

    int selectedDepartment1;
    int selectedDepartment2;
    string notes;
    string searchStringFilters { get; set; }


    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        // Generate 10 departments
        for (int i = 0; i < departmentNames.Length; i++)
        {
            myList.Add(new DeptClass { Id = i, Name = departmentNames[i] });
        }
        _filteredFilters = filters;
    }



    void AddFilter()
    {
        var filter = new Filter
            {
                Department1 = myList.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Id == selectedDepartment1),
                Department2 = myList.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Id == selectedDepartment2),
                Notes = notes
            };

        filters.Add(filter);
        Console.WriteLine($"Search term: {searchStringFilters}");

        // Clear inputs after adding filter
        selectedDepartment1 = 0;
        selectedDepartment2 = 0;
        notes = "";

    }

    void filterExistingFilters()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Search term: {searchStringFilters}");

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchStringFilters))
        {
            _filteredFilters = filters;
            return;
        }
        _filteredFilters = filters
            .Where(f => f.Department1 != null && f.Department1.Name.Contains(searchStringFilters));
    }
}
```